# jQuery - press button to add data to sibling

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button that I want to use to add data to a list. I have managed to get it working when I hard code the div that I want it to go to, but I have multiple buttons to update different divs. I want to use DRY code, so am trying to make each button only update its sibling.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Export</a>
  <div class="title">
      EXPORT LOG
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <ul class="box-list">
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery (the commented out code updates all divs, not just siblings)

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
     $('<li>added text</li><li>more added text</li>').prependTo().parent().find(".box-list");

     // $('<li>added text</li><li>more added text</li>').prependTo(".box-list")
});
```

Comment: please add a fiddle or code snippet

Comment: @T.Bragg no, they don't need to, posting their code is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the jQuery function you can reference `$(this)` which will be the particular `.btn` that was clicked.

Something like:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".box-list").prepend('<li>added text</li><li>more added text</li>')
```

Comment: Thank you @tywhang.  Worked perfectly

Comment: @Tristan glad it worked! Now if you could "Accept" this answer, that would be appreciated. :D

Comment: Is that the tick on the left @tywhang?

Comment: Indeed! You got it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqYmBj

What I did was update your anchor tag to a div tag (just to remove the styling) and adding some CSS. I also broke out your code to make it more readable.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  myBox = $ (this).parent().find('.box-list'); #Finds parent element of the btn and then finds the .box-list element from that parent element.
  newEl = $ ("<li>Added text</li><li>More Added text</li>"); #New element(s) to add
  newEl.appendTo(myBox);#Adds to the box
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can add a little bit more logic to the HTML, and use that to make sure you will always hit the correct list.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
   var containerID = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('<li>added '+containerID+' text</li>').prependTo('#'+containerID+' .box-list');
//     $('<li>added text</li><li>more added text</li>').prependTo(".box-list");

     // $('<li>added text</li><li>more added text</li>').prependTo(".box-list")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a class="btn" rel="export" href="#">Export</a>
  <a class="btn" rel="import" href="#">Import</a>
  <div class="content" id="export">
    <h2>Export log</h2>
      <ul class="box-list">
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  <div class="content" id="import">
    <h2>Import log</h2>
      <ul class="box-list">
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
          <li>Text</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```